# Why does IE8 error on $.post() ["Object doesn't support this property or method"]?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've searched high and low, but can't find this even being mentioned. Using **jQuery 1.4.4** (and no other library), this so far only happens on **Internet Explorer 8**. The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method", and the line it points to is below, at `$.post(`.

#### The JS

The HTML is unexceptional, so I'm just going to post JS.

```
$(window).load(function(){

$("input[type='submit']", ".scope").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // some intervening code defining variables used below...

    //only var which is at all complex
    var inputs = $form.find(":input").serializeArray();

    $.post(
        action,
        inputs,
        function(data){
            var $json = $.parseJSON(data);
            if ( $json.success == true ) {
                if ( testVar == 2 ) {
                    if ( $json.tabkill == true ) {
                        killTab(tabID);
                    } else {
                        loadPane(rID,tabID,"refreshTop");
                    }
                } else {
                    loadPane(rID,tabID);
                }
            } else {
                //modal dialogue error message, excised
            }
        }
    ).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
        if (settings.url == action) {
            alert("Problem calling: "+settings.url+"\n code: "+xhr.status+"\n exception: "+exception);
        }
    });

    return false;
});

//end window load block
});
```

Comment: did you load it up in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see what the error is? IE doesn't hide JS errors from you like some other browsers do. The error is in the JS, not IE.

Comment: To clarify, I did think the error was my fault, not IE's. Just providing context/setup details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your line `ajaxError`.

The problem is that [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post) returns an `XMLHTTPRequest` object, not a jQuery selection. [`ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError) must be called on a jQuery selection.

There are two safe ways around this:

1) Upgrade to jQuery 1.5.  This introduces a new `XMLHTTPRequest` wrapper object [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).  You can use the `error` handler in the way that you are attempting:

```
$.post(
    action,
    inputs,
    function(data){
        /* ... */
    }
).error(function(){
    alert ("Problem calling: " + action + "\nCode: " + this.status + "\nException: " + this.statusText);
});
```

2) Use a call direct to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) and set an `error` handler:

```
$.ajax({
    url: action,
    data: inputs,
    success: function(data){
        /* ... */
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert("Problem calling: " + action + "\nCode: " + xhr.status + "\nException: " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks not only for the answer, but the solution. Not sure how I missed this about ajaxError() until now.

Answer (score 5):

It is because the [`ajaxError()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) method  needs to be called against a jQuery object, and the [`$.post()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method  returns an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Not sure why you don't get an error in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is invalid:

```
).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
        if (settings.url == action) {
            alert("Problem calling: "+settings.url+"\n code: "+xhr.status+"\n exception: "+exception);
        }
    });
```

it should be attached to a jQuery object.

**EDIT**: what patrick said.